# How to access Kong admin API when Kong is deployed using Kong-Ingress-Controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube, kong, kong-ingress

I have installed Kong using Minikube [Kong-Ingress-Controller](https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/kong-for-kubernetes/install/)

Services are visible like below. Now I am trying to find kong admin API so that I can install Konga dashboard on top of it but not sure where to find that

[image]

I am not sure whether I am following the correct process.
Can anyone help me to access the Kong admin API?

Answer (score 1):

use  `kubectl port-forward deployment/ingress-kong -n kong 8444:8444`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this response in a GitHub issue.
https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/59#issuecomment-534380451

Expanding in case the link is invalidated. You need to create a service to expose the admin API endpoint and set the env var and ports for the same in kong ingress controller deployment.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kong-admin
  namespace: kong
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: admin
    port: 8001
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8001
  - name: admin-ssl
    port: 8444
    targetPort: 8444
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-kong
  name: ingress-kong
  namespace: kong
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            ...
            - name: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN
              value: 0.0.0.0:8001,0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
            - name: KONG_PROXY_LISTEN
              value: 0.0.0.0:8000,0.0.0.0:8443 ssl
          image: kong:1.3
          name: proxy
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8001
              name: admin
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8444
              name: admin-ssl
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: proxy
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8443
              name: proxy-ssl
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9542
              name: metrics
              protocol: TCP
```